# Are the type system represented by XmlSchema and the CLS isomorphic

Tags: .net, programming-languages, types, xsd

Can someone please explain this question to me?

> Are the type system represented by
>   XmlSchema and the CLS isomorphic?

[Link](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WhatGreatNETDevelopersOughtToKnowMoreNETInterviewQuestions.aspx)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Means every type defined by XML Schema can be defined in CLS (.NET type system) and vice versa.**

For example, if we have `xs:string` in XML Schema, we have `System.String` in .NET. And If I define this class in C#:

```
public class Foo
{
   public string Bar{get;set;}
}
```

I can represent that in XML Schema:

```
<xs:complexType name="Foo">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Bar" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Comment: Ohhh, gee what a convoluted way of asking a simple question! Thank you.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The question is asking whether the type systems are isomorphic (being of identical or similar form), and they are not. Specifically, the question is there to see if you understand type systems. Is the type system represented by XmlSchema exactly the same as the type system defined in the CLS. You can read more here. http://hyperthink.net/blog/why-xsd-is-not-a-type-system/   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2hf02550(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 3):

NO.

the question is a fancy way of asking if each member in the CLS has corresponding one in XmlSchema.

There are a  lot of matches but mismatches as well so the answer is no - they are not isomorphic.